# Comparison of Global and Local object in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I am comparing two objects. One is global and the other is local objects. If both are not same then and then I want to update UI otherwise not. I am comparing these two at every 3 second interval. The data in the object are coming from file written by firmware program at unknown interval.

In normal case(firmware program is started first and then I open UI window), I have compared these two and getting result what I want, tested well. The problem is coming when The UI is open in chrome already and then I start/restart firmware program. Its every time giving "not same". I manually varified, both are same.

```
var prev_status = $();   //global object

function load_ui(){
    //some code here
}

function ReadFile(){
    //some ajax code
}

function WriteFile(){
    //some ajax code
}

setInterval(function(){ 
    ReadFile(devPublishedUrl, function(status){
        console.log(prev_status, status);      //local object: status
        if (JSON.stringify(prev_status) === JSON.stringify(status)){
            console.log('same');
        }
        else{
            console.log('not same');
            load_ui();
            for(var index in status){
                prev_status[index] = status[index];
            }       
        }
    });
},  3000);
```

What's wrong here? I don't want to update UI at every 3 second without change. The data in local object is given below.

```
{
    "schedule":0,
    "sys":[
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "temp":[
        106,
        32,
        33,
        1645,
        30,
        33,
        1642,
        33,
        30,
        104,
        33
    ],
    "end":[
        0,
        0
    ],
    "fault":[
        0,
        0
    ],
    "ssb":[
        0,
        0
    ],
    "sse":[
        0,
        0
    ],
    "fuel":[
        158,
        193
    ],
    "temp_th":[
        120,
        98
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the data in the global object too please?

Comment: initially there is no data or can say null in prev_status(global object). so for the first time it loads UI and then the data of status copied in prev_status. now prev_status has some data. So It should be same untill the data is not changed from firmware side. Unfortunately that is actually not happening.

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(prev_status, status);` ?

Comment: both are same. I manually verified lots of time in the log. Still here it is giving "not same" always.